# Confusion around CompletionQueue in an async C++ client

Tags: grpc

I have some confusion with regards on how to use `CompletionQueue` for async C++ client. My server is in C#, so my question here is purely around the client sending a request in an async manner to the server.

For reference, here is how I setup my client code to make an async request:

```
template<typename ResponseType, typename AsyncOpExecutor>
bool DoAsyncOp(const AsyncOpExecutor& op, const unsigned int deadlineMs, ResponseType& response)
{
    grpc::ClientContext ctx;
    grpc::CompletionQueue queue;

    const std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReaderInterface<ResponseType>> asyncOpResponse = op(ctx, queue);

    grpc::Status status;
    int requestTag = 1;
    asyncOpResponse->Finish(&response, &status, (void*)requestTag);

    bool result = false;
    bool gotEvent = false;

    do
    {
        const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(deadlineMs);

        void* got_tag;
        bool ok = false;
        const grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus nextStatus = queue.AsyncNext(&got_tag, &ok, deadline);

        switch (nextStatus)
        {
        case grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::TIMEOUT:
            continue;

        case grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::GOT_EVENT:
            assert(got_tag == (void*)requestTag);
                        // ok is always true even if I close the server while request is in progress.
            assert(ok);
            result = status.ok();
            gotEvent = true;
            break;

        // Given that I am creating a new CompletionQueue per request (not using a shared one), is this flag likely to occur?
        case grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::SHUTDOWN:
            result = false;
            gotEvent = false;
            break;

        default:
            result = false;
            gotEvent = false;
            break;
        }
    } while (!gotEvent);

    return result;
}
```

My first confusion is around the best way to setup the `CompletionQueue`. [This answer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18232) seems to suggest that a single `CompletionQueue` can be used across requests. How will this behave if multiple threads use the same queue to make requests. Let's say that I change my code above to use a shared queue rather than creating a fresh one per request.

- How will one thread know that the response it receives is intended for it, rather than for a different thread?
- Do I need to assign a unique tag per thread, and on each thread check that the received tag from the queue matches the one I originally sent?
- If thread A receives a tag intended for thread B, does that mean thread B will be able to query for its tag later, or is that tag lost because thread A saw it first?
- Is there actually a major issue of using a fresh queue per request, rather than sharing?

My second confusion is around `grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::SHUTDOWN` result. If I use a fresh queue per request, and not explicitly call `shutdown` on the queue, is this result ever likely to occur? If yes, what will trigger it? One test I carried out is closing the server while a request is in progress, however rather than getting the shutdown result I got the `grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::GOT_EVENT` result, with status set as `UNAVAILABLE`.

My final confusion is around the `ok` flag. I have read [this answer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12300#issuecomment-331574151), however it's still not very clear. Given the use case and code posted above, if the result I get from the queue is `grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus::GOT_EVENT`, can the `ok` flag be false, and if yes, what will cause it to be false? Again this is purely around the client and not how `CompletionQueue` is handles on the server.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the tag returned from the completion queue to know which completion queue operation initiated this action. You have to make sure that there are not two CQ operations in flight at the same time using the same tag.
2. Each CQ operation in flight simultaneously needs a distinct tag. This applies whether those ops were started from the same thread or different threads.
3. Each tag comes out of the Next function only once. If you have multiple threads calling Next on the same CompletionQueue, they should all be able to process (or pass off) any of the tags registered to that CQ.
4. You can use a fresh queue per RPC, like the sync API actually does internally. It's just less efficient and basically devolves to the sync API in that case since you won't be able to have many operations outstanding at the same time.

You need to call Shutdown at some point and then drain the queue. That's the standard for the API. Otherwise, especially for server CQs, there will likely be leaks. By drain, I mean call Next until it returns false (or AsyncNext until it returns SHUTDOWN).

ok can be false for GOT_EVENT for streaming calls, server-side calls, etc. If you're only looking at client unary calls (like your example), it won't be false. A false ok essentially means that this side of the RPC is broken. The documentation for this is in the header file for the CQ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. Can you please elaborate more on point 3? On test I did was spawning multiple thread that use the same CQ. The result I got was that thread A was able to get tag set by thread B, and thread B was never then able to see that tag again.

Comment: Yes, once a tag comes out in 1 thread it can never be seen by another thread. Each thread can only come out of the CQ exactly once, and any thread can pull any tag from the CQ regardless of which thread put it into the CQ. So typically you'll have each thread inspect the tag and then make a decision of what to do based on the tag only, not based on the thread that started the operation.

Comment: Hmm it seems sharing a CQ is asking for trouble in this case because you have to coordinate many aspects. Having a CQ per request seems the most flexible and safest option. I am specifically talking about the client side here.

Comment: We actually recommend shared CQ in general as it leads to the most efficiency (no work stranding, single point of polling); you just have to use the tag to point to a struct that maintains the current state of that RPC. If you have a separate CQ per request, you're more or less back at the design point of the synchronous API and probably should just use the (much easier) synchronous API.

Comment: The only reason I am using CQ/Async is so that I don't block the UI if the request takes too long to process (i.e. TIMEOUT instead of immediate GOT_EVENT). In this case when I receive TIMEOUT I can notify the UI that the request is still pending. Although a single CQ is recommended, it comes with its own problems of maintaining state and ensuring different requests don't step over each other. A fresh CQ, while maybe not as efficient, eliminates this issue while giving me the ability to use AsyncNext.