# How to use shared completion queue in gRPC asynchronous service

Tags: grpc

Hello I'm trying to implement a DBMS multi-thread gRPC async service. Now I'm stuck at using a shared completion queue. I originally save the tags of RPC calls each thread initiated and would to check the tags against the rpc call return from cq.Next() to make sure I'm having the right thread to check the reply. However, I found out from [Confusion around CompletionQueue in an async C++ client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587604/confusion-around-completionqueue-in-an-async-c-client) that each tag will come out of the cq only once. I'm wondering what will be the best way to make multiple threads share the same cq then? I want each thread to be able to only process the RPC calls it initiate, and I don't want one thread waits on the RPCs created by another thread. Is this possible and how to do that? Are there ways to traverse the queue and only removes the RPC with the matching tag? I did not see a clear solution from the previous stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have two common ways for the `completion queue` and `thread`

1. multiple `completion queue` with multiple `threads`, every `completion queue` for one RPC, and one `thread` focus on one `completion queue`
2. one `completion queue` and multiple `threads`, every `thread` call `completion_queue.Next()`

But if you want them mix, it means you need add another `middleware` to assign event to specific thread. For example, when you initialize the work, you record the `tag`in one `map`, and when call `cq.Next()`, you can check the `map` to find the target `thread`. But I can't find any benefit of this way.